# Managing Python Packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, apt-get

I currently have 2 versions of python installed. 2.7.6 is the default version which shipped with Ubuntu 14. I also have 2.7.10 which I compiled from source installed in /opt/python2.7/

Is it possible to use the Ubuntu repository to install python packages for 2.7.10 which is stored in another directory? I understand I could use pip to do this but I'm just curious if apt-get could do the same thing.

Some of the packages I need are dateutils and Cheetah.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv). And according to documentation you will have:

- Let you change the global Python version on a per-user basis.
- Provide support for per-project Python versions.
- Allow you to override the Python version with an environment variable.
- Search commands from multiple versions of Python at a time. This may be helpful to test across Python versions with tox.

Answer (score 0):

Python packages are hosted by Python Software Foundation, which maintains the official repositories. PyPi deals only with python packages.

"apt-get" deals with Debian distros packages and it doesn't contain packages that **need a "runtime"**.. like Python packages, NodeJS packages, ...

However, You can manually build python packages from sources. [Take a look at this post](https://docs.python.org/2/install/)